# Show captured image

Tags: android, camera, android-camera2

I have implemented the google sample of the [camera 2 api](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic), but I can't figure out how to show she captured image with a button overlay. All examples I can find just saves the image to storage. I need to obtain the image and show it in the app.

Comment: use BitmapDrawable

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: you can convert the image to `BitmapDrawable` and call `setBackground(Drawable)` to set it as the background of your view